# How do I copy an excel sheet embedded in an outlook e-mail into an excel worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-outlook-2010

I was sent an e-mail with some data from an excel sheet embedded in it. I want to extract that data to another Excel spreadsheet. When I try to copy and paste it, it insists on pasting it as an object which does not allow me to work with the data.

Comment: You're pasting it after opening it and doing a `Select All... Copy`?

Comment: If you right click on the embedded worksheet, is there a "Save as..." option?

Comment: The right click only gives a save as picture option. I am not doing a select all copy. Just clicking the data and copying it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the table in the outlook email.
2. open a new excel sheet and select [Paste Special](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/use-paste-special-to-insert-static-or-linked-data-into-excel-HP001108276.aspx)
3. Paste as text

[image]

Comment: That does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Found a trick copy your table in the Outlook email command+C then paste the table into a new document in evernote. Then copy the table in evernote and paste it into excel. This worked for me. I'm using Office for Mac 2011